# SSO SAML 2.0 - EntityDescriptor is returning null

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

For some reason I am unable to set the EntityDescriptor and it is returning null.

```
EntityDescriptor metadata = null;
metadata = (EntityDescriptor)context.Cache['https://domain.info/blah'];
```

This EntityDescriptor is needed in order to instantiate a SAML 2.0 Assertion Consumer Factory. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `context.Cache['https://domain.info/blah']` returns null.

Comment: Correct. I am trying to determine why it is returning null and not returning the EntiryDescriptor.

Comment: From the code you've supplied here, there is no way to find out why. You need to be more specific. Include code and info on where `context.Cache['https://domain.info/blah']` is set.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the Cache object for the current application domain because it was unable to find it and returned null. This was because the Uri did not match the case of the metadata item key value in the Web.Config. i.g. `<add key="https://Domain.Info/Blah" metapath="c:\saml\meta\blah_samlMeta.xml" metauri="https://domain.info/blah" />` Changing the key value to lower case worked for me.